# RadioButton rendering issue in API 19

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I am using 3 radiobutton inside the radio group. When i preview it in the API 19 i am getting rendering issue saying **"Invalid drawable Vector"** and **Failed to parse file C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Fuict1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable\abc_btn_radio_material.xml**

XML:

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffffff">


 <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Online"
    android:text="Online"
   />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Sd"
    android:text="StreetFood"
    />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Rt"
    android:text="Restaurant"
    />

</RadioGroup>
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
 }
```

Comment: May be problem with the appcompat alpha version you using. Use App compat Stable version 23.2.1

Comment: does this problem occurs only in rendering? Can you run it ? because sometimes it may be possible that editor cannot show your layout.

Comment: Yes, in rendering only.

Comment: It is the problem of the layout showing only, You can run your project normally. So no need to worry because sometimes preview behaves weird.

Comment: @SID - I used 23.2.1 it is working fine while rendering. But crashing in the older Android versions.

Comment: add that crash report